# How to create a new Moodle user from Sharepoint?

Tags: workflow

How to create a new Moodle user directly in mySQL with PHP script from Sharepoint? or is there a way to create user (write in MySQL) directly from SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to create a custom Web part (Visual Studio, WSP package, etc.) and connect to MySQL from the code-behind of the Web part (you can connect MySQL from .NET, see for instance http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

In general you are not able to create users in SharePoint. You can only assign users from other systems. By default user have to be stored in Active Directory but you can add additional LDAP and Database authentication mechanism.

You also cannot run a php script in SharePoint. All you can do is to include Moodle user management via an iFrame.

For more information on authentication look at this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx